Python code elements to allow indention without flow control structures
When using Vim, I prefer to have one scheme for demarcating folds across all programming languages and even text files for meeting notes.  It saves me from having to finagle different schemes.  It has worked for decades, but now that I'm trying to develop Python experience, it is running into a kink.  I can't arbitrarily indent blocks of code.  This is what I might try in another language:
# Calculate flux capacitances

    This is code
    It calculates flux capacitance

# Generate summary statistics for each group

    This is more code
    It groups the flux capacitances by spaceship size
    For each group, it generates min, max, mean

The indented code becomes automatically hidden away by folds.  However, Python requires flow control structures for indentation.  To fulfill this, I prepend if True::
if True: # Calculate flux capacitances

    This is code
    It calculates flux capacitance

if True: # Generate summary statistics for each group

    This is more code
    It groups the flux capacitances by spaceship size
    For each group, it generates min, max, mean

It adds some cognitive noise.  In lengthy, complex code, anything that cuts down on cognitive noise helps.  Is there a less noisy code element/scheme that I can use?  I would prefer not to depart from my simply fold scheme based on indentation.
Another reason for seeking an alternative to if True : # Section heading comment is that some section headings require a multi-line comment, in which case if True: needs to occupy its own line after the heading, i.e., yet more cognitive noise.
# This is a multi-line
# section heading
if True:
    More code
    It does stuff

One workaround might be the following, though it is rather unconventional and therefore could interfere with trying to make sense of lots of code at once:
if True: # This is a multi-line
# section heading
    More code
    It does stuff


Comments in Python don't have to match the indentation structure.

@9769953: In Vim, folds can be demarcated by flow control structures, but I'm trying to find a way to not depart from a very simple indentation based fold scheme which has worked for all different kinds of files for decades.  I'm not sure I would make the move it it was necessary (I'm definitely leaning toward not doing so).

@John Bayko: I just added a final example demonstrating what you said.  It save space but is cognitively weird, so it's unclear to me whether it helps.

I don't understand why you need the if True: In all examples where you use it, you can remove it, provided that you have an outer structure (like a def), which anyhow is best practice.

@trincot: I'm still inexperienced with Python.  Can you please provide an example?  I want the code to run (not define a class or function).  I also want the code to share the name space with other code in the script.

It is good practice to place all code in functions / classes. The driver code, at the top level, calls one function, possibly called main. That function will call other functions, so that no function has more than let's say 20 lines of code.

This is exploratory data analysis rather than production code.   It changes rapidly, a lot, with one section's usage of dataframes from another section also changing a lot.  I keep the namespace clean with del at the end of each section, but because it is very dynamic, I need the shared namespace.

@user2153235 you may want to look into interactive notebooks like Jupyter, this seems like it might be more your speed

I appreciate the suggestion, but having seen and superficially test-driven Jupyter, I much prefer Vim, and Spyder's console.  There are even Python fold schemes in Vim, but I was hoping to find a quick-and-dirty way of staying with the simple indentation-based folds.

def calculate_flux(): # code that calculates flux will give you the required indentation.

I might be missing something, but this will not allow the function code to share the namespace with the rest of the script?  My comment above describes the rapidly changing code and dependencies.  Also, more code is needed to invoke the function.
